# Intel XDK iOS Ad Hoc builds crash on iOS after installation

Tags: ios, build, intel-xdk

I am experiencing a problem with the iOS builds the last days. Intel XDK generates the builds successfully and I install them without any problems on my iPod (iOS version 6.1.6) through iTunes. The problem comes when I open the installed applications - they are started successfully as expected and 1 second after that just quit. I pulled the crashed reports from the device and I noted that they have the same type of exception (EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)) thrown by the iOS, for instance:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3349529e 0x3b11597a 0x33498e02 0x3349752c 0x333eef64 0x1f6bf4 0x1f69a4 0x1f6a94 0x1f6a08 0x33dac0f0 0x3346a67e 0x33469ee4 0x33468cb2 0x333dbeb8 0x333dbd44 0x36f8e2e6 0x352f12fc 0xc6e8a 0xc6e34)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3b613350 0x3b602000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x3b58a11e 0x3b55b000 + 192798
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x3b5c696e 0x3b55b000 + 440686
3   libc++abi.dylib                   0x3ab64d4a 0x3ab61000 + 15690
4   libc++abi.dylib                   0x3ab61ff4 0x3ab61000 + 4084
5   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x3b115a74 0x3b10d000 + 35444
6   libc++abi.dylib                   0x3ab62078 0x3ab61000 + 4216
7   libc++abi.dylib                   0x3ab62110 0x3ab61000 + 4368
8   libc++abi.dylib                   0x3ab63594 0x3ab61000 + 9620
9   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x3b1159cc 0x3b10d000 + 35276
10  CoreFoundation                    0x333dbf1c 0x333d3000 + 36636
11  CoreFoundation                    0x333dbd44 0x333d3000 + 36164
12  GraphicsServices                  0x36f8e2e6 0x36f89000 + 21222
13  UIKit                             0x352f12fc 0x3529a000 + 357116
14  tMobileApp2                       0x000c6e8a 0xbf000 + 32394
15  tMobileApp2                       0x000c6e34 0xbf000 + 32308
```

I just want to mention that I did not have such a problem before. I have an old build (from 15th of February or something) of the same application 'tMobileApp2' and it is still running perfectly when I install it on the device.

Does anybody have an idea of what might be going wrong and why the applications quit suddenly once opened?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: Thanks, Kerni! I will try to do it later today to get some meaningful info from the crash report. By the way, this started happening after the last updates of the Intel XDK system. I already reported this at their official support forum site, but still waiting for a reply.

Comment: By the way, I am communicating with the Intel development support team on this issue and they are working on it. It seems it is a kind of problem with the cordova.js library according to what other users say who are facing the same issue at the moment: "it's the cordova.js include, i'm experiencing the same issue and pinpointed the culprit. now it's the dev's turn to figure out what's going on with cordova.js..."